# Laravel - How do we can get both the value AND the text of a select option?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this in my blade

```
//Blade file   
<select name="rule_type">                                                   
    @foreach($getRuleType as $ruleType)
        <option value="{{$ruleType->promo_rule_typet_id}}">{{ $ruleType->rule_type }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And I'm getting the value of each option in the controller:

```
// Controller
$form_data = $request->form_data;
parse_str($form_data, $my_array_of_vars);

$rule_type = $my_array_of_vars['rule_type'];
```

This works perfectly, but I need to get the text of the options as well as the value so they each have their own variable in the controller.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: As far I have understand your query you are wishing to get both values ( {{$ruleType->promo_rule_typet_id}} and {{ $ruleType->rule_type }} ) via $my_array_of_vars['rule_type']. Right?

Comment: That's correct. I already get the value of promo_rule_typet_id as is standard, but I'd like to get the text value as well for rule_type

Comment: ok I have posted my answer. Hope it may be helpful to you

Comment: Please note that **HTML can be edited** which means that the submitted id - name combination **might not exist** in your original `$getRuleType` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested, it may be done the following ways.

```
// Blade
<select name="rule_type">                                                   
@foreach($getRuleType as $ruleType)
     <option value="{{$ruleType->promo_rule_typet_id}}-{{ $ruleType->rule_type }}">{{ $ruleType->rule_type }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>



// Controller
$rule_type = explode("-", $my_array_of_vars['rule_type']);
//$rule_type[0] will be the $ruleType->promo_rule_typet_id
//$rule_type[1] will be the $ruleType->rule_type
```

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear that. @TomN.